# How to feedback in visual studio 2017 when report a crash crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Ran into problems with first run of Visual Studio 2017 rc; tried reporting with the "Report a Problem" feature within VS, that blew up too. Wonder what the best way is to report a problem with "report a problem"?

[image: Report a problem crash]

Comment: visual studio 2017 ? Ok maybe one day microsoft will stop. If "report a bug"... bug, try to send a mail... but they don't like it. Or switch to visual studio 2015 update 3 :p. [Using the Report a Problem feature rather than email, Twitter, blog comments, or other methods will help us address your issue faster because it provides more contextual data to help us efficiently analyze, diagnose, and fix reported issues.](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/supportvs2017rc/#4bf0d4707aab3a678)

Comment: This is still an issue...

Comment: @IanKemp email at the address in the answer below; they are prompt & helpful

Comment: @aateeque already did yesterday, haven't got a reply yet, presumably they're on holiday. I was more complaining about the fact that the built-in feedback tool is still broken, even after I updated to the latest version of the RC. Would be interested to know if you still have this issue?

Comment: No, fixed issue; check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<SKU>\Common7\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.dll.config`. It has a bug in that the `runtime` node is closed inside the `system.net` node, i.e. `</runtime>` before `<system.net>`. Basically that file has invalid XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to try and report your problem to Visual Studio. Sorry you ran into an issue while using Report a Problem. If you'd like to report issues to us about that, please email us at [vsfeedback@microsoft.com](http://vsfeedback@microsoft.com). We'd like to understand more about what happened and how we can fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always file a bug on http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio.  Since this is just a web site, it doesn't depend on VS stability at all.  Issues filed on Connect might take a little while to get routed to the product team, but AFAIK they will all get filed as bugs in the product database.

To make it more useful for the product team, *please try to capture a dump of the crash and upload that with your Connect issue*.  That will also help it get triaged and investigated quicker than going back and forth trying to reproduce the problem.